# Нет перевода слова "Answer" при появлении чужого ответа в процессе написания своего

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, ответы, нет-в-transifex

Если в процессе написания ответа на существующий вопрос, другой участник даст ответ на этот же вопрос, то в шапке сайта появляется баннер вида:

If someone posts an answer to the question when you are already trying to answer (wrote some sentences and draft is saved), then the banner appears in the page header:

> [image: новый ответ]

Если кликнуть на ссылке "загрузить новый ответ", то на странице появляется текст нового ответа, однако заголовок содержит непереведённое слово "Answer":

If you click on the link, new answer's body appears, but title contains english word "Answer" (instead of russian "ответ"):

> [image: 1 Answer]

Если страницу обновить принудительно, то появляется уже русский текст "1 ответ".

After manual page refreshing title changed to russian "1 ответ".